# Uniform convergence of $f_n(x)=n\sin (\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2})$ on $[0,a],a>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

I want to show the uniform convergence of $f_n(x)=n\sin (\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2})$ on $[0,a],a>0$.

I tried it as follows:

$f_n(x)=n\sin (\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}-2n\pi)=n\sin\left(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}+2n\pi}\right)\sim n\left(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}+2n\pi}\right)\to \frac{x^2}{4\pi}$.

It follows that $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f:x\mapsto \frac{x^2}{4\pi}$.

To show uniform convergence, I want to show that the sequence $y_n:=\sup_{x\in [0,a]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ converges to $0$.

$\begin{align}
f_n(x)&=n\left((\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}-2n\pi)-(\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}-2n\pi)^3 \frac 1{3!}\right)+o(1/n)\\
&=\left(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4\pi^2+(x/n)^2}+2\pi}\right)-\left(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4\pi^2+(x/n)^2}+2\pi}\right)^3\frac{1}{n^23!}+o(1/n)
\end{align}$

$\begin{align}|f_n(x)-f(x)|&\le \left|\left(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4\pi^2+(x/n)^2}+2\pi}\right)-\frac {x^2}{4\pi}\right|+\left(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4\pi^2+(x/n)^2}+2\pi}\right)^3\frac{1}{n^23!}+o(1/n)\\
&\le a^2\left(\frac 1{4\pi}-\frac 1{\sqrt{4\pi^2+(x/n)^2}+2\pi}\right)+o(1/n)\\
&\le a^2\left( \frac 1{4\pi}-\frac 1{\sqrt{4\pi^2+(a/n)^2}+2\pi}\right)+o(1/n)\end{align}$

It follows that $y_n\to 0$.

Is my proof correct? Thanks.

**Note:**

$(1): f_n(x)=n\sin (\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}-2n\pi)=n\sin t= n(t-\frac {t^3}{3!}) +nR(t),$ where $t=\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}-2n\pi=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}+2n\pi}\le \frac {a^2}{4n\pi}$ and $R(t)$ is the remainder term.

$(2): |R(t)|\le t^5\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{t^{2k-2}}{(2k+3)!}\le \frac{a^{10}}{{4\pi}^{5}n^5}\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a^{4k-4}}{(4n\pi)^{2k-2}(2k+3)!}}=M\frac{a^{10}}{{4\pi}^{5}n^5}$.

The blue colored series converges and is hence bounded by some $M>0$.

It follows that $|n R(t)|\le M\frac{a^{10}}{{4\pi}^{5}n^4}$, whence $R(t)=o(1/n)$.

Comment: It would be easier to follow your argument if you explained how you got from one step to the next. Also, your use of $\sim$ looks like "this is sort of equal to" which is not well-defined. You claim in several places the error is $o(1/n)$ without showing how it was gotten. Thus, we don't know if that estimate (which is defined by a limit) is dependent on $x$ or not.

Comment: @robjohn: Thanks a lot for the comment :). The use of ~ is in reference to the following: Given two sequences $(x_n)$  and $(y_n)$, $x_n\sim y_n$ iff $\lim_n \frac{x_n}{y_n}=1$. I’ll edit my post shortly to include more details.

Comment: @robjohn: I have edited my post.

Comment: The $o(1/n)$ term *is* dependent on $x$ and so you will need to show *how* it depends on $x$ to be able to use it. For example, as $x$ gets large, $\left(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4\pi^2+(x/n)^2}+2\pi}\right)\sim nx$ and $\left(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4\pi^2+(x/n)^2}+2\pi}\right)^3\frac{1}{n^23!}\sim\frac{nx^3}6$. Since $f_n(x)\le n$ for all $x$, there is no way that the error is bounded by $o(1/n)$ independent of $x$.

Comment: @robjohn but I took care of that in R(t). Right?

Comment: No. "The blue colored series converges and is hence bounded by some $M\gt0$." While it is true that that series converges for each $a$, it has not been shown how that $M$ depends on $a$.

Comment: @robjohn: $a$ is given. So it doesn't matter that M depends upon $a$?

Answer (score 1):

I carried out the program of $a-b=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a+b}$ twice to good effect along with some trigonometric identities.

For $x\gt0$, the Mean Value Theorem says
$$
\begin{align}
f_0(x)&=1-\cos(x)\ge0\tag{1a}\\[9pt]
f_1(x)&=x-\sin(x)\ge0\tag{1b}\\[3pt]
f_2(x)&=-1+\frac{x^2}2+\cos(x)\ge0\tag{1c}\\
f_3(x)&=-x+\frac{x^3}6+\sin(x)\ge0\tag{1d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: $-1\le\cos(x)\le1$
$\text{(1b)}$: for some $c\in(0,x)$, $f_1(x)-f_1(0)=(x-0)f_0(c)\ge0$
$\text{(1c)}$: for some $c\in(0,x)$, $f_2(x)-f_2(0)=(x-0)f_1(c)\ge0$
$\text{(1d)}$: for some $c\in(0,x)$, $f_3(x)-f_3(0)=(x-0)f_2(c)\ge0$

Thus, for $x\ge0$, $\text{(1b)}$ and $\text{(1d)}$ say
$$
0\le x-\sin(x)\le\frac{x^3}6\tag2
$$
Furthermore, for $n\ge\frac{x^2}{2\pi^2}$, $\frac{x^2}{4\pi n}\le\frac\pi2$ and therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
&\sin\left(\frac{x^2}{4\pi n}\right)-\sin\left(\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}\right)\tag{3a}\\
&=\sin\left(\frac{x^2}{4\pi n}\right)-\sin\left(\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}-2\pi n\right)\tag{3b}\\
&=\sin\left(\frac{x^2}{4\pi n}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}+2\pi n}\right)\tag{3c}\\
&=\scriptsize2\sin\left(\frac{x^2\left(\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}-2\pi n\right)}{2\cdot4\pi n\left(\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}+2\pi n\right)}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x^2\left(\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}+6\pi n\right)}{2\cdot4\pi n\left(\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}+2\pi n\right)}\right)\tag{3d}\\
&=\scriptsize2\sin\left(\frac{x^4}{2\cdot4\pi n\left(\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}+2\pi n\right)^2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x^2\left(\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}+6\pi n\right)}{2\cdot4\pi n\left(\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}+2\pi n\right)}\right)\tag{3e}\\
&\le\frac{x^4}{64\pi^3n^3}\tag{3f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3b):}$ $\sin(x)$ has period $2\pi$
$\text{(3c):}$ $a-b=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a+b}$
$\text{(3d):}$ $\sin(a)-\sin(b)=2\sin\left(\frac{a-b}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)$
$\text{(3e):}$ $a-b=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a+b}$
$\text{(3f):}$ $\sin(x)\le x$ and $\cos(x)\le1$

Note that since $\frac{x^2}{4\pi n}\le\frac\pi2$, $\text{(3c)}$ shows that
$$
\sin\left(\frac{x^2}{4\pi n}\right)-\sin\left(\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}\right)\ge0\tag4
$$
Thus, for $n\ge\frac{x^2}{2\pi^2}$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2}{4\pi n}-\sin\left(\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}\right)
&=\frac{x^2}{4\pi n}-\sin\left(\frac{x^2}{4\pi n}\right)\\
&+\sin\left(\frac{x^2}{4\pi n}\right)-\sin\left(\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}\right)\tag{5a}\\
&\le\frac16\left(\frac{x^2}{4\pi n}\right)^3+\frac{x^4}{64\pi^3n^3}\tag{5b}\\
&=\frac{6x^4+x^6}{384\pi^3n^3}\tag{5c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(5a):}$ break the sum into two pieces
$\text{(5b):}$ apply $(2)$ and $(3)$
$\text{(5c):}$ simplify

$(2)$ and $(4)$ show that $\text{(5a)}$ is $\ge0$. Therefore, if we multiply $(5)$ by $n$, we get
$$
0\le\frac{x^2}{4\pi}-n\sin\left(\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}\right)
\le\frac{6x^4+x^6}{384\pi^3n^2}\tag6
$$